Angular unit test, how to mock a property of window object
After I upgraded to Angular 17, the CLI generated this file when it found that my library was using DomSanitizer for sanitizing HTML string, which seems to be useful.
I covered 100% my angular library code with unit tests, however only for this newly generated function, there is a 50% chance that the test coverage appears to be 100% by the test and 50% appears to be lower (like partial highlighted in yellow color).


This is very annoying because, if my test passes in codacy with 100% in the first commit, it can give a lower percentage in the second commit. and then it will not allow me to merge the PR.

I need to mock that the browser does not support the trustedTypes API.
Here is the generated function by the CLI
let policy;

function getPolicy() {
  if (!policy) {
    try {
      policy = (window as any)?.trustedTypes?.createPolicy('ngx-highlightjs', {
        createHTML: (s: string) => s,
      });
    } catch {
      // trustedTypes.createPolicy throws if called with a name that is
      // already registered, even in report-only mode. Until the API changes,
      // catch the error not to break the applications functionally. In such
      // cases, the code will fall back to using strings.
    }
  }
  return policy;
}

export function trustedHTMLFromStringBypass(html: string): string {
  return getPolicy()?.createHTML(html) || html;
}

So I tried to mock window.trustedTypes here:
it('[Content-Security-Policy (CSP)] highlight element when trustedTypes is not supported by the browser', async () => {
    // Save a backup to the "trustedTypes" API
    const trustedTypesBackup: any = window['trustedTypes'];
    // Delete it from the window object
    delete window['trustedTypes'];

    // Perform a test that execute the "getPolicy()" function
    component.code = testJsCode;
    fixture.detectChanges()

    const highlightedCode: string = hljs.highlightAuto(testJsCode, null).value;

    await afterTimeout(100);
    expect(directiveElement.nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe(highlightedCode);

    // After test passes, return the trustedTypes API to the window object
    window['trustedTypes'] = trustedTypesBackup;
});

Full code:
@Component({
  template: `<code [highlightAuto]="code"></code>`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HighlightAuto]
})
class TestHighlightComponent {
  @Input() code: string;
}

describe('HighlightAuto Directive', () => {
  let component: TestHighlightComponent;
  let directiveElement: DebugElement;
  let directiveInstance: HighlightAuto;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHighlightComponent>;

  const testJsCode: string = 'console.log(&quot;test&quot;)';
  const testHtmlCode: string = '<div class=&quot;my-class&quot;></div>';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HighlightAuto, TestHighlightComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: HighlightLoader, useValue: highlightLoaderStub },
        { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHighlightComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    directiveElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(HighlightAuto));
    directiveInstance = directiveElement.injector.get(HighlightAuto);
  });


  it('[Content-Security-Policy (CSP)] highlight element when trustedTypes is not supported by the browser', async () => {
    // Save a backup to the "trustedTypes" API
    const trustedTypesBackup: any = window['trustedTypes'];
    // Delete it from the window object
    delete window['trustedTypes'];

    // Perform a test that execute the "getPolicy()" function
    component.code = testJsCode;
    fixture.detectChanges()

    const highlightedCode: string = hljs.highlightAuto(testJsCode, null).value;

    await afterTimeout(100);
    expect(directiveElement.nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe(highlightedCode);

    // After test passes, return the trustedTypes API to the window object
    window['trustedTypes'] = trustedTypesBackup;
  });
});


P.S: afterTimeout is a helper similar to tick, it waits for time in ms.

